# How can I update the cell index of datatables?

Tags: jquery, datatable, row

I would like to get the data of the row by row number in my datatable.

```
$('.table').on( 'draw.dt', function() {
    console.log(table.row(0).data());
    console.log(table.row(1).data());
}
```

The problem is, that the columns are sorted and that changes the number for the row. So to really get the data of row 0 and 1 I have to write it like this:

```
console.log(table.row(27).data());
console.log(table.row(3).data());
```

This would give the correct result, but of course this does not help me, because I need to search by the number of the position (after sorted) in the datatable.

Comment: do you want to get the data by row number for original data list and not after sorting, right?

Comment: yes. for example with the number 0 I want to get the data of the first row in the table after sorting

Comment: In this case you can store original data list in separate variable and then load the data to datatable. Whenever you need to get the data with row number you can refer to the variable where you have saved original data list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This updates The index of the cell:

```
  table.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
    table.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
      cell._DT_CellIndex.row = i;
    } );
  } ).draw();
```